# Import Previously Initialized Object (Python)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am creating my first python package.

In `__init__.py`, I import and open an object `App` from a module.

```
from app import App
app = App()
```

`app.py`:

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        #Create App
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("1000x550")
        self.title("Game")
        self.container = tk.Frame(self).grid()
```

Then, in another module `game.py`, I need to access `app` and `app.container` created when `app` was initialized in `__init__.py`.

I have tried:

```
from app import App
# Does not retrieve variables

from __init__ import app
# Does not retrieve object

from app import App
app = App()
# Intialized the object twice
```

Comment: What does "does not retrieve variables" mean? Also, why are you creating an instance of `App` in an `__init__`? That is not normally how you do things.

Comment: @BryanOakley If I try to call `App.container`, it errors that it does not exist. This is also my first package, so I am not familiar with the normal way

Comment: `App.container` doesn't exist because it is an instance variable, not a class variable. To access `container` you must do `App().container`.

Comment: There are many tutorials. Have you tried any of them? For example, http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-create-a-python-package/ and https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating an instance of `App` in your `__init__.py` file. A package should only provide the *definition* of objects. There are exceptions of course, but when just starting out you shouldn't be doing that.

Your `__init__.py` file should have only this:

```
from app import App
```

Assuming that's in a folder named "mypackage", anywhere you need an app, you would do:

```
from mypackage import App
app = App()
```